# why audio.pause() can not working with TypeScript, but audio.play(); works very well?

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, html5-audio

I have a problem with the pause() function of HTMLMediaElement. I tried to pause my audio, but nothing happens. play() works every time very well:

```
export class personalCard { 
j = 0;

playAudio(){
let aud = new Audio ('../../assets/aud/Magdalena_Su_ß.opus');


this.j= this.j + 1;

if(this.j % 2 == 0){
  aud.pause();
  console.log('Pause');
   }

else if(this.j % 2 != 0){
  aud.play();
  console.log('Play');
   }

 }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="volume" (click)="playAudio()"></button>
```

I can also see on console the log 'pause', but the aud.pause(); can never working. I don't use any frameworks for audio. 
can anybody help me to solve the problem?

thank you very much,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for access to the pause(), mute() or load() the variable, aud must be declared in the class for global access.

Solution:

```
export class personalCard { 
j = 0;
aud = new Audio ('../../assets/aud/Magdalena_Su_ß.opus');

playAudio(){

this.j= this.j + 1;

if(this.j % 2 == 0){
  aud.pause();
  console.log('Pause');
  }

else if(this.j % 2 != 0){
  aud.play();
  console.log('Play');
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: Where is  ??

var sound = new Howl();

Comment: @InamurRahman He's not using howler, he's using HTML5 Audio.